# error: passing ‘const xxx’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I know that this question has been asked before, and I red all the answers but I didn't find something that helped me. Hopefully you can !
So, I have a class named Vecteur which has two attributes: dimension (size of the table) and the table of values.
And in the copy constructor when I try to copy the values of the Vecteur &v to the values of 'this' it gives me an error, and I don't know why because I think that I overloaded the [] operator !
(When I was trying to figure it out I put this->t[i] = v.t[i] and it worked ! but i found it weird because t is private).

Vecteur.h

```
#ifndef VECTEUR_H
#define VECTEUR_H
#include "typedef.h"

class Vecteur
{
    public:
        Vecteur(int);
        Vecteur(const Vecteur&);
        ~Vecteur();
        scal& operator[](int);
    protected:
    private:
        int dim;
        scal *t;
};

#endif // VECTEUR_H
```

Vecteur.cpp

```
#include "Vecteur.h"
#include "typedef.h"

Vecteur::Vecteur(int dim)
{
    this->dim = dim;
    t = new scal[dim];
}

Vecteur::~Vecteur()
{
    delete[] t;
}

Vecteur::Vecteur(const Vecteur &v)
{
    for(int i=0; i<dim; i++){
        t[i] = v[i];//The error
    }
}

scal& Vecteur::operator[](int i){
    return t[i];
}
```

Comment: You have defined this:

    scal& Vecteur::operator[](int i){
        return t[i];
    }

now you have to define the `const` flavour of your operator, like this

    const scal& Vecteur::operator[](int i) const {
        return t[i];
    }

otherwise you're violating the contract.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Which contract I'm violating?

Comment: `const Vecteur &v` is constant. You cannot call a non-constant method on it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes I tried to do that but it does not work ! In the header file I wrote: scal& operator[](int) const; And in the source file I wrote: scal& Vecteur::operator[](int i)const{
    return t[i];
} Is the syntax correct?

Comment: `const scal& Vecteur`. There are 2 "const".

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Did that too and it gives me error: prototype for ‘const scal& Vecteur::operator[](int) const’ does not match any in class ‘Vecteur’
I really don't know why, and I spent lot of time trying to figure this out

Comment: of course you need to define it in your class as well. I'd do it only in the class (inline) and would drop it in cpp (else you cannot use a template): in your class `const scal& operator[](int) const;`